# Trigonometric identity from Fourier matrix

Tags: trigonometry

When I try to multiply the real and the imaginary part of Fourier matrix, I have encounter the below trigonometric identity :$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \cos \frac{2ik\pi}{n}\sin \frac{2il\pi}{n}=0$$ where $1\leq k,l \leq n-1$ and $k,l \in \Bbb{N}$. But I don't know how to verify it. Please help me :-)

Comment: maybe use  fact and cosine and  sine function are orthogonal  to each  according their inner product?

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\:$ $p=2(l+k)$, $q=2(l-k)$, $j=\sqrt{-1}$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}Cos(\frac{2ik\pi}{n})Sin(\frac{2ik\pi}{n})=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2Cos(\frac{2ik\pi}{n})Sin(\frac{2ik\pi}{n})\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}Sin(\frac{2i(l+k)\pi}{n})+Sin(\frac{2i(l-k)\pi}{n})\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}Sin(\frac{2i(l+k)\pi}{n})+Sin(\frac{2i(l-k)\pi}{n})\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}Sin(\frac{ip\pi}{n})+Sin(\frac{iq\pi}{n})\right) =\frac{1}{4j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{jip\pi}{n}}-e^{\frac{-jip\pi}{n}}+e^{\frac{jiq\pi}{n}}-e^{\frac{-jiq\pi}{n}})\right)$$ But

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{jir\pi}{n}}=0$$ if $r$ is Even integer.